# Downgrade Xamarin.iOS in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2017

I have to use an older version of `Xamarin.iOS` (10.12) because our Mac building server runs on an older version, the problem is that I am not allowed to update the `Xamarin.iOS` framework on the Mac.

I wasn't able to find older installers for `Visual Studio 2017` nor Xamarin. There was also a blog post about the `Xamarin Updater` but the extension is no longer available.

Is it possible to downgrade `Visual Studio 2017`  and/or its components and if yes how?

Comment: Log in to Xamarin.com and you can find download links of older releases.

Comment: Where exactly I can’t find a download page?

Comment: Right top corner, your profile -> Dashboard->Downloads under My Account. Then you should see a banner like "Looking for the version before 15.5? Get the previous servicing update of 15.4 here."

Comment: Yes but I am looking for Xamarin.iOS 10.12 releases. This isn’t available there.

Comment: You probably can write to Xamarin support. Very likely they don't support that release any more.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Visual Studio for Windows**
Downgrading Xamarin.iOS to the version 10.12 in Visual Studio means that you need to downgrade VS to the version [15.3](https://releases.xamarin.com/category/xamarin-ios/page/3/).
You need to contact the support team for the download link since they provide only the link for the [version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/productinfo/installing-an-earlier-release-of-vs2017) `N-1`.

*I'll just leave the links, they may be useful to someone.*
**For Xamarin Studio:**
It's possible, either downloading Xamarin.iOS from here:

https://dl.xamarin.com/MonoTouch/Mac/xamarin.ios-10.12.0.18.pkg

or directly from the repository, which contains every version:

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/releases

Comment: I don’t like to update the Mac version of Xamarin.iOS I like to update the version of Xamarin.iOS in Visual Studio 2017 on Windows.

Comment: This was really helpful when trying to find another version, thanks ;)