# VS for Mac: Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class: CPTAnimationDelegate

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-mac

Updated to the latest Xamarin Visual Studio for Mac version 7.5 (build 1254) and now our solution won't compile with linking SDK only enabled. Worked fine prior to this update. We have the CorePlot DLL from the prior component store package referenced as components are no longer supported. Now it seems CorePlot is causing linking issues:

> Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class:
>   CPTAnimationDelegate

Multiple of similar to the above.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the error installing an old version of xamarin.ios that I have dowloaded from here:

[Xamarin.iOS
Version: 11.6.99.33](https://dl.xamarin.com/MonoTouch/Mac/xamarin.ios-11.6.99.33.pkg)

I got that link from here:
[Downgrade Xamarin.iOS in Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48525386/downgrade-xamarin-ios-in-visual-studio-2017)

To install close visual studio (I am using mac) and install the package then open visual studio and verify the version of xamarin.ios in About Visual Studio community-> Show details where you will find:

Xamarin.iOS
Version: 11.6.99.33 (Visual Studio Community)
Hash: 60a17f1c
Branch: xcode9.3
Build date: 2018-02-07 05:56:11-0500

and this 11.6.99.33 is the version of xamarin.iOS with which I could recover my project after having updated to 11.10.1.177.

same issue:
[forums.xamarin.com](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/330203#Comment_330203)

Answer (score 0):

A bug report was filed and a [solution provided by Xamarin](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/4063).