# can Xamarin.iOS[13.6.0.12] use xcode10.2 with devicesupport sdk13.2(from xcode11.3)

Tags: xcode, xamarin.ios, hackintosh

since I'm using a hackintosh which is limited in macos10.13, and its highest `xcode` is 10.1,

but Xamarin.iOS is upgraded to 13.6 and it want `ios sdk 13.2` in `xcode11.3`.

I have manully download it and copy the `DeviceSupport/13.2` directory to `xcode10.1`'s corresponding location,

but it seems it's not recognized by the xamarin build process, it still prompt:

`MTOUCH : error MT0091: This version of Xamarin.iOS requires the iOS 13.2 SDK (shipped with Xcode 11.2). Either upgrade Xcode to get the required header files or set the managed linker behaviour to Link Framework SDKs Only in your project's iOS Build Options > Linker Behavior (to try to avoid the new APIs). [/Users/wellbye/repos/m/my/xamarin/mb.iOS/mb.iOS.csproj]`

if I set `MtouchLink` to `SdkOnly`, it still produce error:

`/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/13.6.0.12/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIResponder.g.cs(204): error MT4162: The type 'UIKit.IUIMenuBuilder' (used as a parameter in UIKit.UIResponder.BuildMenu) is not available in iOS 12.2 (it was introduced in iOS 13.0). Please build with a newer iOS SDK (usually done by using the most recent version of Xcode). [/Users/wellbye/repos/m/my/xamarin/mb.iOS/mb.iOS.csproj]
  /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/13.6.0.12/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIResponder.g.cs(744): error MT4162: The type 'UIKit.UICommand' (used as a parameter in UIKit.UIResponder.ValidateCommand) is not available in iOS 12.2 (it was introduced in iOS 13.0). Please build with a newer iOS SDK (usually done by using the most recent version of Xcode). [/Users/wellbye/repos/m/my/xamarin/mb.iOS/mb.iOS.csproj]`

is there anyway to rescure the my old pc for xamarin developing?

Comment: Hi , you use vs for mac or vs for pc , you need to downgrade the version of vs . Have a look at this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48525386/downgrade-xamarin-ios-in-visual-studio-2017) .

Comment: hi, @JuniorJiang-MSFT , I don't like to downgrade my version because other co-workers are using the latest one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

got it working:

1. copy `${xcode11}/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk` to corresponding location of old xcode.
2. copy `${xcode11}/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/13.2` to corresponding location of old xcode.